# Origin of exception, Elmah Logs

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah, error-logging

I am looking to find the source ie the page, line number where the exception occurs, can we find that in elmah logs?.

We are trying to trap and handle the error.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Elmah isn't for trapping and handling errors. It's merely a log of unhandled exceptions. Examine the stack trace it provides you.

Comment: hey mason, thanks for dropping by. I just wanted to know on what page the error is coming from. i tried e.Exception.StackTrace but the reference is blank and there is no information there. tried the following : void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception.GetBaseException() is HttpRequestValidationException)
        e.Dismiss();
}

Comment: If you look at the details in Elmah, it will tell you what page the error from. There's no need for you to filter anything. Just look at the logged exceptions.

Comment: Is your problem that the stack trace doesn't contain file and line info?

Comment: i am checking on this..

Comment: If this is the case, check out this article: [Include filename and line number in stack traces](https://docs.elmah.io/include-filename-and-line-number-in-stacktraces/)

Comment: hi all, i still dont get the filename, line number and stacktrace, shows null.

Comment: if (e.Exception.GetBaseException() is HttpException)
            {

                StackTrace st = new StackTrace(e.Exception, true);

         
                StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(0);

                string fileName = frame.GetFileName();


                string methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name;

                int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();

                int col = frame.GetFileColumnNumber();

            }

Comment: thanks for your reply Thomas, will try that..